# How do I remove an already-committed file from a repository using GitKraken?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I know it is possible to do this via the command line, but it would be much more convenient if it is possible to do this using GitKraken. I have not found a way, does anybody else know? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a file that is checked in, be it by command line, windows explorer or whatever, GitKraken will realize and the file will appear under "Unstaged Changes" as deleted. You can stage and commit the file to remove it from your repository.

The first part, the file deletion, can not be done in GitKranken, as far as I know. As you correctly mentioned, `git rm` does the deletion and stages the deletion in one step. This is not possible in GitKraken.

I have found no source or documentation on this, it's solely based on my experience, but I'm pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option that allow you to delete files using gitkraken. Click the option "view all files", then right-click and select delete. From there, just commit the change.

[image: delete-already-committed-file-using-gitkraken-1]

[image: delete-already-committed-file-using-gitkraken-2]

[image: delete-already-committed-file-using-gitkraken-3]